# How to open the Electronic nautical chart S-57 data?

Tags: file-formats, s-57

Anyone know how to open the Electronic nautical chart S-57 data by using GIS software e.g. Arcview, QGIS? and converted it to general GIS / CAD formats.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your question is simply about viewing the S57 files (extension .000), then you will be happy that GDAL supports that format for reading files. As a result any software using GDAL, like Qgis, can open S57 files. [See here](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/s57.html) for documentation on the S-57 ENC file format.
Also [see here](https://opencpn.org/wiki/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=opencpn:opencpn_user_manual:charts:chart_formats) for a very nice Opensource navigation software.

If you want to write to S57, I do not think that is possible with FOSSoftware yet. Maybe we will have one by the time S100 is released.

Comment: Here is a working link to the GDAL S-57 page: http://www.gdal.org/drv_s57.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a free add-on from ESRI to view S57 files.

http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/esri-s57

Answer (score 0):

If your ENC is from US NOAA it can be converted at [ENC-Direct](https://encdirect.noaa.gov/).