# Garmin/Navionic charts in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I'm looking for an option to import nautical maps (mostly for depth data) into QGIS. So far, I managed to import NOAA .KAP files, but coverage and resolution of some areas are not very good. Is there a chance to import data from Garmin or Navionics into QGIS (I know that this is an expensive option). Or does anyone know a free alternative?

I'm using QGIS 3.4.10 and am a beginner, complex operations to import data are not an option for me right now (except with very detailed instructions for QGIS 3.4.10).

Comment: Do you already have nautical maps? If so, what format are they in? If not, you might have better success by asking on [OpenData.se] for nautical data in any of the format that QGIS can accept.

Comment: This related question might be helpful: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/60884/81764